# Hibernate: implement POP method

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to implement classic a POP method in Data Access Layer: retrieve some object in memory and delete it from the database. The problem is that if I delete it after retrieving I can't use it in code, so is there anysolution?

Right now I am removing it in code after some actions with the object.

Thank you

UPD#1:

```
public Notification pop() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    return (Notification) session.createCriteria(Notification.class)
        .uniqueResult();
}
```

I want to remove an object after retrieving it, but still be able to access it in my code.

Comment: Can you give some codes to demonstrate your problem? Thanks

Comment: if you remove an object you can't use it in code ?  Your code just attempts to return a unique resutl from notification, but as there are no restrictions (and assuming you have more than one record) it will throw an exception

Comment: I want to: 1. populate object and remove it in DAL 2. use returned object in code (maybe use some cached version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an idea about what you are trying to say. You should make a copy constructor for your `Notification` class and do the following:

```
public Notification popAndRemove(){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    Notification notification = session.createCriteria(Notification.class)
        .uniqueResult();    

    Notification newNotification = new Notification(notification);

    session.delete(notification);
    return newNotification;
}
```